# Override AddCampaign action in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, button-overrides, action

I wish to override the 'AddCampaign' action on the Campaign object in Lightning.
We have an 'existing' override in place already for Classic (which works :) )
The override is a Visual Force Page.

The 'Setup' page for the Action Override says that you '***You can set different override behavior for Salesforce Classic, Lightning Experience, and mobile.***'

OK, how? There is no option to specify a different override on the page, only an option for Classic.

Am I missing something?

OK then, even if I can't specify a 'different' override for Lightning, does the 'Classic' override we have specified work in Lightning?

It appears (to me) that the override is completely ignored when running in Lightning.

So the question :

Can I in fact override the 'AddCampaign' action in Lightning? (and yes, using the Classic override would work for me) :)

Believe it or not, I would actually even be happy(er) if I could be pointed to the documentation where it explicitly states that you cannot do this. (Even though the Setup page says you can)

Answer (score 0):

*Most* buttons support different overrides for each. For example, here's Campaign Edit:

[image: Campaign Edit Override]

It appears that "List" buttons do not (yet?) support separate overrides. For now, you'll have to use Visualforce.

Comment: One of the points was that it appears the 'Classic' Visual Force page override does not even work in Lightning. So , forget the point that we cannot specify a 'separate' Lightning override. I'm after confirmation that the already existing override (a Visual Force Page) that works in Classic does or does NOT work in Lightning. Evidence suggests that it doesn't, and I am trying to find official documentation that says that.

Comment: To allow us to specify  'separate' overrides is relatively new, I get that, but before it was introduced, Classic overrides (using a VF page) still work in Lightning (for the most part !! :) ). For AddCampaign, that appears to NOT be the case.

Comment: @PeterByrne I'm not sure what to tell you. Did you enable the page for LEX?

Comment: Yep, good point. We actually did not have it enabled initially. Hopeful that that was the issue , but alas no :(